# Restricting Date Value of Parameter in SSRS

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, parameters

I have two parameters: Start Date and End Date, that filter records to include only those in this range.

Issue one: End date cannot be earlier than Start Date - I have a solution currently that just hides the data objects and displays a text box telling the user to re-enter a valid date range. Maybe there's a better solution

(Bigger) Issue two: I need to restrict users selecting Start date to only dates after a certain date eg. 5/25/2013. I tried a function in custom code to check and change, but unfortunately Parameters in custom code are read-only. I thought of a check in custom code and refreshing the parameter to default (an appropriate value eg. 5/25/2013) but I haven't been able to do that.

Something like this would be ideal:

```
Public Function DateCheck()
If (Report.Parameters!Open.Value < DateValue("5/25/2013"))
Report.Parameters!Open.Value =  DateValue("5/25/2013") 'or refresh to default value
End If
End Function
```

Also, where do I put the Code.DateCheck() call if it works?

Looking forward to positive responses

Answer (score 0):

I create a second but hidden parameter tor both that will modify them as required e.g. a second `open` called `open_mod` that is automatically set by a dummy sql like (example is in Oracle):

```
Select greatest(@open, '25/MAY/2013') from dual
```

Comment: Forgive me if I misunderstand. So you have a second parameter that gets whichever value's greater but which one then filters your report? Is it open_mod?

Comment: That's correct. I would just use `open` as a way to interact with the user and not actually use it in the report.